# Reconstruct a dynamic form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

**Context**

In my application, I have members belonging to several organizations.

For example, say a user Tom belongs to the organizations Sun and Canonical. The user John doesn't belong to any organization.

I would like to add a little form on the profile page of John when Tom (or anyone belonging to some Organization) is visiting John's profile. This form enable Tom to recruit John in an organization.

**My attempt**

I've created a `AddUserOrganizationForm`; this form takes two parameters: the user visiting the profile page (`person_adding`, Tom in our case) and the user we are visiting the profile page (`person_to_add`, John in our case). I need `person_adding` in order to know the organizations he belongs.

```
class AddUserOrganizationForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, person_to_add, person_adding, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddUserOrganizationForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        req_orgas = Q(members=person_adding)
        req_not_orgas = ~ Q(members=person_to_add)
        orgas = Organization.objects.filter(and_(req_orgas, req_not_orgas))
        # listing all the orga containing "person_adding" but not "person_to_add"
        orgas = [(o.id, o.name) for o in orgas]
        self.void = (orgas == [])
        self.fields["person_to_add"] = forms.IntegerField(widget =forms.HiddenInput(), initial=person_to_add.id)
        self.fields["orga"] = forms.ChoiceField(label="Add this user to",
                                               choices=orgas)
```

**My problem**

In the view, when I want to reconstruct my form with `form = AddUserOrganizationForm(request.POST)`, I'm stuck because I need the `person_to_add` which is one field of `POST` (I can easily get `person_adding` since it's `request.user`). And it sounds creepy to directly extract information from `POST` for after use a validation form mechanism.

Comment: Don't you have the username or Id of the person available to you in the view where you generate the profile page, where you'd be calling such a form?

Comment: Non the view I use to add the user to the orga is not the same which I use to display profile's page.